# a bit weird random number generator c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a code of random number generator, and it must have these specifications:

- the code must have 2 letters followed by 6 digits
- the letters are constant and same for each code
- digits shouldn't EVER be duplicated.

I will generate 1000 of codes this way. I know how to generate such code but if I make 1000 of them and I don't want them to be duplicated plus the letters... honestly having some bad time here.

```
private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    string newLine = Environment.NewLine;
    int nums = rnd.Next(100000, 999999);
    txtNumbers.Text = nums.ToString();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1001; i++)
    {
        nums = rnd.Next(100000, 999999);
        txtNumbers.Text =  txtNumbers.Text +newLine + nums.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, none of the 1000 generated codes can match any of the existing other ones?  Is that what you mean by "_I know how to generate such code but if I make 1000 of them and I don't want them to be duplicated plus the letters_"?

Comment: What does this mean: "the letters are constant and same for each code"? Basically you need to store them and check if the collection contains newly generated code (I suggest Hashset). For the digits, generate them sequentially and eliminate duplicates.

Comment: side note: Wait until the end of your method to fill the control's .Text propery instead of concatinating it in a loop.

Comment: Please don't add a *new* question if an existing one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39726043/) is closed. Improve that one instead.

Comment: Based on the fact you know how to actually generate according to your spec, the linked duplicate shows how to avoid duplicate numbers

Comment: @jamiec if you read my question carefully you could realise it is not all about the duplicate. People wants to start war instead of helping.

Comment: I read your question *very* carefully. What do you think I misunderstood? and what in the hell are you talking about a "war" ?!?!

Comment: Plus before you accuse me of something, you might like to look at how many questions I answer in a given week!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a dictionary or a list to check for duplicates while you generate.

```
private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HashSet<int> dupTest = new HashSet<int>();
Random rnd = new Random();

string newLine = Environment.NewLine;
int nums = rnd.Next(100000, 999999);
txtNumbers.Text = nums.ToString();
while(dupTest.Count<1000)
{
    nums = rnd.Next(100000, 999999);
    if(!dupTest.Add(nums))
       continue;
    txtNumbers.Text =  txtNumbers.Text +newLine + nums.ToString();
}
}
```

check out Scott's answer below and use a Hashnet

Comment: Why use `Dictionary<int,int>` when a `HashSet<int>` would work just as fine, you could then use `if(dupTest.Add(nums))` because `Add` returns false if you try to add a duplicate number.

Comment: As unlikely as it is, this could go on for ever trying to generate a number. Especially as you get more numbers in the hashset. Its far better to generate a sensible set of values, randomize it, and pick the first x numbers.